# Can't connect to ClearDB database after resetting password

Tags: node.js, heroku, cleardb

I am trying to deploy a very simple nodejs api through Heroku and utilizing the clearDB add on so I can connect to the MySQL db the api utilizes. I had everything connected and working then realized I had hard coded and exposed the database user and password information. I reset the password on clearDB to reset the exposed information. So far I have created environment variables locally and the config variable for the new password on Heroku but now the app crashes anytime I try to connect to the db, is there somewhere else that the new password will be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearDB stores the username and password information inside the URL to the db so if you only updated it in the config variable for the password you will also need to update it in the variable containing the URL string as well.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was going to be something stupid that I missed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).